# Encountering 'running scripts is disabled' error when running Yarn command in VS Code, how to resolve it?

Tags: yarn-v2

Encountered this error while trying to run Yarn command in VS Code
yarn : File C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn.ps1
cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this
system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

- yarn watch:client
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityExce  
  ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
  ```

In order to fix this, I tried these steps and using CMD shell and it fixed the error, likewise you could still run thsi command in your vs Code Terminal

Step 1: First, you have to need to open the command prompt and run this command.
set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser

When you run this command, you can see that your system has set all policies for the current user as remotely. It will take few seconds to complete this process.

Step 2: Now you have to run the second command on your system. This command is:
Get-ExecutionPolicy

When you have run this command your system has a show “RemoteSigned”. If you have received this message, then your problem will be solved. Now you have to go to the next step to view the list of policies which policy has been updated by the last commands.

Step 3: To view their policy, you need to run this command in your command prompt:
Get-ExecutionPolicy -list

That's all... And there you go! Your problem got Solved!!